# Reversing/recoding survey items in R

Tags: r, reversing

I am working on a survey document on CVS by R. 
Before the analysis, I want to reverse the coding of some items on 4 likert scale. To turn 1 to 4, 2 to 3, 3 to 2, and 4 to 1.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to subtract from 4 (assuming these are the only values)

```
4- v1 + 1
#[1] 2 2 1 2 3 2 4 3 1 3 3 4 1 4 1 2 1 4 4 1
```

comparing with original vector

```
v1
#[1] 3 3 4 3 2 3 1 2 4 2 2 1 4 1 4 3 4 1 1 4
```

The same code can be applied on `matrix`.  After subset the columns `[, 5:10]`, do the calculation, and update by assignment (`<-`) for the same columns

```
m1[, 5:10] <- 4 - m1[, 5:10] + 1
```

---

If there are more elements and want to only change values 1 to 4

```
i1 <- v1n %in% 1:4
v2 <- v1n
v2[i1] <- 4- v2[i1] + 1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(48)
v1n <- sample(1:9, 20, replace = TRUE)

set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(1:4, 20 * 10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10)
```

Comment: Thank you, Akrun. I was not clear at my question: I want to to this on a matrix, though. For example on a matrix from column 5 to column 10, I want to reverse all item values.

Comment: @sebgok  You can use the same code and assign `m1[, 5:10] <- 4 - m1[, 5:10] + 1`